# Content inside div unclickable

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, position

I have a div and I have content inside of it.  When I make this div position:relative; it renders all the content inside unclickable only in IE7.  When I change it to absolute, static or fixed it works again. Only happens in IE7.  Anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: I can't give you a *specific* reason...other than to say IE is mildly retarded

Answer (score 2):

See this post: http://verens.com/archives/2005/07/15/ie-z-index-bug/

Answer (score 1):

I will say you have some z-index conflict and the DIV goes on top of your clickable elements rendering them unclickable. The solutions can vary, can you post the whole HTML code you have.